# Site Master Page Issue in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage, visual-studio-2012, system-master-page

I have a custom master page (that includes top navigation, breadcrumb, etc.) created using Visual Studio 2012 for SharePoint 2013. And I am using it as a site master page. Now I want to use this site master page as a system master page as well.

When I do that and go to a document library and click on upload the document, I see the top navigation as well as the breadcrumb in the upload document page. How can I get rid of these things from the upload the document page, but keep them in rest of the pages?

Answer (score 1):

Add 'ms-dialogHidden' class to nav and breadcrumb div or section.

Answer (score 1):

As @Aveenav is suggesting, it may be that your custom master page is missing the "ms-dialogHidden" CSS class on the navigation controls that is design to hide these elements in a modal dialog.

From a sample master not the css class:

```
<div class="ms-dialogHidden">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation ms-dialogHidden" runat="server">
 ...
</div>
```

I suggest you look at an OOTB master page for reference.  In addition, you may want to review the following posts:

[SharePoint 2013 CSS classes that suck and save the day](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-css-classes-that-suck-and-save-the-day/)

[An easier way to hide page elements from the SharePoint dialog box](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2011/09/hide-page-elements-sharepoint-dialog-box/)